# My cycle never enters a if statment

Tags: c

I guess my problem is very simple. I check a string to see if the value is all alphabetical and if it is it will `j = 0` to continue to the next instruction if it's not `j = 1` to continue asking the user the name. If you fail the first time it'll set the `j = 1` and it will never enter the `j = 0` if it's all alphabetical.

```
for(p = 0; p < 50; p++)
{
    if(isalpha(name[p]) == 0)
    {
        printf("Invalide value.\n");
        j = 1;
        break;
    }
    **if(isalpha(name[p]) != 0)
    {
        j = 0;
    }**
}
```

I also tried the next code:

```
for(p = 0; p < 50; p++)
{
    if(!isalpha(name[p]))
    {
        printf("Invalide value.\n");
        j = 1;
        break;
    }
    **if(isalpha(name[p]))
    {
        j = 0;
    }**
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: `nome[p]` and `name[p]`? Why two different array names? If they're supposed to the same, then why the two ifs? Both cases wouldn't be true, so `if (!islpha(...)) { j = 0; break }` would all you need. just set `j=1` before you start the loop. if it's 0 afterwards, then you hit a non-alpha char.

Comment: I tried that and it doenst work. My code is much larger but i'm having a problem with this little part.

Comment: Why don't you use `else`?

Comment: Tried that and i didn't work out.

Comment: Well, there is something that you are not showing us.

Comment: You do have a `break`.

Comment: Is `**if` intended to mark the line? It's a syntax error. If you want to mark a line, it's better to use a syntactically valid comment.

Comment: **if was to be "bold". It's my first time here and i'm getting used for asking questions.

Comment: Why are you so sure your `name[p]` is actually alphanumeric? Have traced it with debugger?

Comment: I'll leave now and will be back tomorrow guys. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: name[p] is an stdin. It's the name of the person. If the person enters a numerical character it will give a warning "Invalid input". I'm getting used to a debugger. I'm learning programming for two weeks now.

Comment: You probably don't always have exactly 50 characters long name. C usually uses NUL-terminated 8-bit char strings, meaning there is a 0-byte after last character byte. Use that to detect end of string.

Comment: So. You are saying to add a if statment if null is found and do a break?

Comment: `NULL` is null pointer, not be mixed with "NUL" character `'\0'` or just `0`. But yeah, when iterating over chars of string in C, test for that to detect end of string (and when making strings, be sure to put 0 at its end).

Answer (score 0):

You have a small typo. In the second comparison, you spell the variable as `nome` instead of `name`, making it an entirely separate check.

Also, if you want the loop to terminate when `isalpha`, put a `break` statement after `j=0;`.

Comment: The program is in Portuguese and i forgot to change that. As long as the name/nome goes it's all right in the original code. I tried placing a break after "j = 0" and it never entered this cycle.

Comment: What do you mean "all right"? Do you have same name or different ones in the actual code?

Comment: Yes. You got that :) In the actually code it's allright. The names match. Here i forgot to change the second "nome"

Comment: Then please update the question to fix that problem. Ideally, the question should include code that actually reproduces the problem you're having.

Comment: btw, i dont have break in the  j = 0 because it will get out of the cycle if the first character will be alphabetical. If the second isnt alpabethical it will never get there.